# White space after footer only in firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm making a master page for my friend and I'm getting a little error only in Firefox a white space after the footer I've look at all the other question about this problem and none of them helped, I have a pen with the problem:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>White space</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Some Content I m thinking to put here.
    </body>
</html>
```

Can I use a Firefox prefix

http://codepen.io/J_Mack/pen/OVdOgX

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, just add `overflow: hidden` to prevent from blank margin at the bottom of the page:

```
#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: none;
    height: 196px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    clear: none;
    width: 960px;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After messing around with your codepen for a while I found that if you add `overflow: hidden;` to your #footer it removes the problem, however it would be better to use this as a temporary fix and find out the actual problem later on, if you didn't want to do that there are ways of identifying a browser and adding styles based on that which I suppose is one way of doing it but yeah using overflow does fix the problem, or at least did for me it is just frowned upon as it doesnt actually inform you of what the problem is.

Or see the answer above....

Answer (score 0):

I always start my CSS files with:

```
*, ::before, ::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This way I make sure that the browsers don't add any padding or margin so I have full control over it. In your case adding `* {margin: 0}` fixes the problem but you would have to compensate for the margins on other elements that lost the default margin.